# .npmrc variable substitution doesn't work in docker

Tags: linux, docker, npm

I have an `.npmrc` file locally that works just fine when I used it with `npm ci` or `npm i` and is able to fetch items
from an artifactory instance.
However, when I try to use substitution in `.npmrc` (which the documentation clearly shows as supported), it fails

I've already tried to use buildx to avoid cooking in credentials, but isn't available to me.
I am also explicitly setting them as `ENV` knowing they're available in the final image, but only as a means to test things out.
I get the same error when set on `RUN NPM_AUTH=$NPM_AUTH npm ci`

*Why is this portion not being interpolated? Without it, I am left to hardcode credentials into the file! Using coded credentials does, actually work*

output on Ubuntu, x86

```bash
-> % env | grep NPM && cat .npmrc && sha256sum .npmrc && uname -a && npm -v && node -v
NPM_AUTH=eHh4eHh4OnNvbWVwYXNzCg==
NPM_VIRTUAL_REGISTRY_REPO_URL=someartifactory/artifactory/api/npm/svcshub-npm/
NPM_PUBLISHER_EMAIL=user@foo.com
@simulator-framework:registry=https://${NPM_VIRTUAL_REGISTRY_REPO_URL}
strict-ssl=false
always-auth=true
email=${PUBLISHER_EMAIL}
//${NPM_VIRTUAL_REGISTRY_REPO_URL}:_auth="${NPM_AUTH}"
37bfcdc56b8ce961ab0f6fccad213002d796a8df29f5702acfa9ec27575df6bc  .npmrc
Linux ip-10-40-246-209 5.15.0-1028-aws #32-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 9 12:28:07 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
10.2.4
v20.11.0
```

Here's the Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine as caps
ARG NPM_VIRTUAL_REGISTRY_REPO_URL
ARG PUBLISHER_EMAIL
ARG NPM_AUTH

ENV NPM_VIRTUAL_REGISTRY_REPO_URL=$NPM_VIRTUAL_REGISTRY_REPO_URL
ENV PUBLISHER_EMAIL=$PUBLISHER_EMAIL
ENV NPM_AUTH="$NPM_AUTH"
WORKDIR /root
#configured to talk to an artifactory instance
COPY .apk-repositories /etc/apk/repositories 
RUN apk update --no-cache --no-check-certificate &&  \
    apk add --no-cache --allow-untrusted --no-check-certificate nodejs npm
COPY . ./
```

and this is how I build it:

```bash
sudo DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 docker build --build-arg "NPM_AUTH=$NPM_AUTH" \
--build-arg PUBLISHER_EMAIL=$PUBLISHER_EMAIL \
--build-arg NPM_VIRTUAL_REGISTRY_REPO_URL=$NPM_VIRTUAL_REGISTRY_REPO_URL \
-t someartifactory/project-repository/caps:CES-2242 --target=caps .
```

Then bring up a shell in that image and run those same commands

```bash
-> % sudo docker run -it someartifactory/project-repository/caps:CES-2242 sh
~ # env | grep NPM && cat .npmrc && sha256sum .npmrc && uname -a
NPM_AUTH=eHh4eHh4OnNvbWVwYXNzCg==
NPM_VIRTUAL_REGISTRY_REPO_URL=someartifactory/artifactory/api/npm/svcshub-npm/
NPM_PUBLISHER_EMAIL=user@foo.com
@simulator-framework:registry=https://${NPM_VIRTUAL_REGISTRY_REPO_URL}
strict-ssl=false
always-auth=true
email=${PUBLISHER_EMAIL}
//${NPM_VIRTUAL_REGISTRY_REPO_URL}:_auth="${NPM_AUTH}"
37bfcdc56b8ce961ab0f6fccad213002d796a8df29f5702acfa9ec27575df6bc  .npmrc
Linux cfecff44e173 5.15.0-1028-aws #32-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 9 12:28:07 UTC 2023 x86_64 Linux
```

These files are identical. Although, I was surprised that the `uname -a` produced identical results.

Now, I run the following locally on my ubuntu machine:

```bash
-> % rm -fR node_modules && npm ci
(node:299350) Warning: Setting the NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED environment variable to '0' makes TLS connections and HTTPS requests insecure by disabling certificate verification.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-class-properties instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread@7.20.7: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-object-rest-spread instead.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.

> credit-app-processing-subgraph@2.1.0 prepare
> husky install

husky - Git hooks installed

added 1235 packages, and audited 1236 packages in 19s

128 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

2 moderate severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

Ok, looks good. Now inside the container:

```bash
~ # rm -fR node_modules && npm ci
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-class-properties instead.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread@7.20.7: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-object-rest-spread instead.
npm ERR! code E403
npm ERR! 403 403 Forbidden - GET https://someartifactory/artifactory/api/npm/svcshub-npm/@typescript-eslint/utils/-/utils-6.21.0.tgz
npm ERR! 403 In most cases, you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! 403 a package version that is forbidden by your security policy, or
npm ERR! 403 on a server you do not have access to.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2024-02-13T01_03_50_807Z-debug-0.log
```

So, if I go look at this log file I see numerous entries like:

```bash
~ # grep "GET 403" /root/.npm/_logs/2024-02-13T01_03_50_807Z-debug-0.log
1295 http fetch GET 403 https://someartifactory/artifactory/api/npm/svcshub-npm/@typescript-eslint/utils/-/utils-6.21.0.tgz 6614ms (cache skip)
1296 http fetch GET 403 https://someartifactory/artifactory/api/npm/svcshub-npm/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin/-/eslint-plugin-6.21.0.tgz 6609ms (cache skip)
1300 http fetch GET 403 https://someartifactory/artifactory/api/npm/svcshub-npm/brace-expansion/-/brace-expansion-2.0.1.tgz 6509ms (cache skip)
1301 http fetch GET 403 https://someartifactory/artifactory/api/npm/svcshub-npm/minimatch/-/minimatch-9.0.3.tgz 6511ms (cache skip)
1302 http fetch GET 403 https://someartifactory/artifactory/api/npm/svcshub-npm/@typescript-eslint/typescript-estree/-/typescript-estree-6.21.0.tgz 6507ms (cache skip)
1303 http fetch GET 403 https://someartifactory/artifactory/api/npm/svcshub-npm/@typescript-eslint/types/-/types-6.21.0.tgz 6509ms (cache skip)
1304 http fetch GET 403 https://someartifactory/artifactory/api/npm/svcshub-npm/@typescript-eslint/visitor-keys/-/visitor-keys-6.21.0.tgz 6511ms (cache skip)
1305 http fetch GET 403 https://someartifactory/artifactory/api/npm/svcshub-npm/@typescript-eslint/scope-manager/-/scope-manager-6.21.0.tgz 6509ms (cache skip)
1306 http fetch GET 403 https://someartifactory/artifactory/api/npm/svcshub-npm/minimatch/-/minimatch-9.0.3.tgz 6544ms (cache skip)
1307 http fetch GET 403 https://someartifactory/artifactory/api/npm/svcshub-npm/brace-expansion/-/brace-expansion-2.0.1.tgz 6544ms (cache skip)
1308 http fetch GET 403 https://someartifactory/artifactory/api/npm/svcshub-npm/@typescript-eslint/typescript-estree/-/typescript-estree-6.21.0.tgz 6544ms (cache skip)
1309 http fetch GET 403 https://someartifactory/artifactory/api/npm/svcshub-npm/@typescript-eslint/visitor-keys/-/visitor-keys-6.21.0.tgz 6547ms (cache skip)
1310 http fetch GET 403 https://someartifactory/artifactory/api/npm/svcshub-npm/@typescript-eslint/scope-manager/-/scope-manager-6.21.0.tgz 6539ms (cache skip)
1311 http fetch GET 403 https://someartifactory/artifactory/api/npm/svcshub-npm/@typescript-eslint/types/-/types-6.21.0.tgz 6549ms (cache skip)
1312 http fetch GET 403 https://someartifactory/artifactory/api/npm/svcshub-npm/@typescript-eslint/types/-/types-6.21.0.tgz 6558ms (cache skip)
1313 http fetch GET 403 https://someartifactory/artifactory/api/npm/svcshub-npm/@typescript-eslint/visitor-keys/-/visitor-keys-6.21.0.tgz 6553ms (cache skip)
```

Now, if I go and look at the logs on the artifactory server, I see this (xxxxxx being 'me') :

```
2024-02-13T01:04:01.463Z [jfrt ] [WARN ] [566133550b2f3f5a] [o.a.s.SecurityServiceImpl:1581] [p-nio-8443-exec-9385] - User xxxxxx is blocked due to incorrect login attempts till 1707786256421
2024-02-13T01:04:01.514Z [jfrt ] [WARN ] [99c3c4ae5abf408d] [o.a.s.SecurityServiceImpl:1581] [p-nio-8443-exec-9271] - User xxxxxx is blocked due to incorrect login attempts till 1707786256421
```

I even tried fetching one of these resources with curl (and I was suprised):
on linux:

```bash
-> % cat .netrc && cat .netrc | sha256sum # sha256 represents actual username and pass
machine someartifactory
user xxxxxx
password somepass
1bd1cf6f3f3949a61236e1423d6aee437fea71966711d83a3e23c6ae41a9c546  -
```

in the docker container:

```bash
~ % cat .netrc && cat .netrc | sha256sum # sha256 represents actual username and pass
machine someartifactory
user xxxxxx
password somepass
1bd1cf6f3f3949a61236e1423d6aee437fea71966711d83a3e23c6ae41a9c546  -
```

In docker:

```bash
curl -svnLf https://myarifactory.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/npm/svcshub-npm/@typescript-eslint/utils/-/utils-6.21.0.tgz > /dev/null
> GET /artifactory/api/npm/svcshub-npm/@typescript-eslint/utils/-/utils-6.21.0.tgz HTTP/1.1
> Host: myartifactory.jfrog.io
> Authorization: Basic OkFLQ3A4cFJxxxxxhzOFJYOVo=
> User-Agent: curl/7.81.0
> Accept: */*
```

I got identical results in the container, but here was the surprise: When I decoded that basic authorization, it threw away username
and basically just gave me : `:${NPM_PSW}`

Ok, so I decided to throw away the username and rerun. Works fine on linux, fails in the docker container.

I am at a total loss for why this works on native linux (and mac), but not in a container.